# How do Italians make a statement a question?

Tags: grammar, interrogatives

In many germanic languages you change the word order if you want it to be a question.

Statement: You are tired.

Question: Are you tired?

If I put “Are” at the beginning it becomes a question.

*Sei un po' stanco?* in Italian means “Are you tired?” but it also sounds like a statement.
In Italian you cannot simply change the word order in order to make it a question. How do Italians then ask questions? By adding a question mark in texts and changing the pitch in speech?

I could write: “You are tired?” But it sounds a bit weird in English unless you were surprised that the person was tired.

Is this how you ask questions in Italian?

Comment: The question is “Sei stanco?". The difference is in intonation: a descending tone for the statement “Sei stanco.” an ascending tone for the question.

Comment: You are right, it is all about the intonation. This is a characteristic of all romance languages. 

Changing word order when expressing questions is also present in romance languages (e.g. in French, *Elle vient...* vs *Vient-elle...*).

Comment: @Easymode44 And French, lacking the same tone features as Italian, uses something like *Est-ce que tu est fatigué?*

Comment: @egreg That depends. *Est-ce que* is used, but not always. In informal contexts, French often makes the questions exactly as Italian (maybe with a somewhat less pronounced intonation)

Comment: I don't really see the need for explanation, when your Germanic example works the same; "You're tired? Already?" or "You're tired; time for bed."

Answer (score 12):

> How do Italians then ask questions? By adding a question mark in texts and changing the pitch in speech?

That's exactly how you do it, for questions implying a yes/no answer.

Comment: ... But then you get Australian Question Intonation/ Upspeak; e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_rising_terminal

Answer (score 6):

That's correct; it's explained on the [Wikipedia page on Italian grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_grammar#Syntax):

> Questions are formed by a rising intonation at the end of the sentence (in written form, a question mark). There is usually no other special marker, although [wh-movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wh-movement) does usually occur. In general, intonation and context are important to recognize questions from affirmative statements.
>
> - *Davide è arrivato in ufficio.*     (David has arrived at the office.)
> - *Davide è arrivato in ufficio?*   ("Talking about David… did he arrived at the office?" or "Davide has arrived at the office? Really?" - depending on the intonation)
> - *Perché Davide è arrivato in ufficio?*    (Why has David arrived at the office?)
> - *Perché Davide è arrivato in ufficio.*    (Because David has arrived at the office.)
> - *È arrivato Davide in ufficio.*   ("It was **David** who arrived at the office" or "David **arrived** at the office" - depending on the intonation)
> - *È arrivato Davide in ufficio?*   (Has David arrived at the office?)
> - *È arrivato in ufficio.*  (He has arrived at the office.)
> - *(Lui) è arrivato in ufficio.*    (**He** has arrived at the office.)
> - *Chi è arrivato in ufficio?*  (Who has arrived at the office?)

Comment: To these you can also add "Perché è arrivato Davide in ufficio?" (Why has **David** arrived at the office?) and "Perché è arrivato Davide in ufficio." (Because **David** has arrived at the office), where in both cases the emphasis is on the fact that David has arrived and not someone else.